# I don't have permission to log on via Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, permissions, remote-desktop

We're setting up a new server and we've set up a Windows Server Edition 2003 virtual machine off of that server so users outside can Remote Desktop in. We're now in the process of doing updates etc before telling everyone it's live.

Only problem is, I don't have permission.

I've added myself to the Remote Desktop Users via Active Directory, created a Remote_Access group and added that to the local users and groups on compmgmt.msc and after all that didn't work I added myself directly to those groups and it still didn't work.

I checked around on the internet for people with similar problems and the only solution I found was unticking the "Deny user from Remote Desktop" (or something similar) but when I checked my account the box wasn't ticked. Everyone else can access it but I can't, I'm a domain admin account if that helps.

thanks in advance.
HugoNumber1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who comes across a similar problem in the future here's how ya solve it:

group policies! go to the domain server and override the domain server's group policies, on the server you cant connect to log in as your admin account and go to cmd and do gpupdate /force to refresh the policy and then users can log in

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

i think its better to access all users remote desktop connection and its good to remove yourself and allow every body and allow none lan connection after all if you have firewall or etc turn it off

post screen shots and exact error

thanks (i have no 50 rep so i cant comment and please dont vote me down)

Comment: sorry, I cant post images (not a rep 10 :/ )

Comment: (You must have 50 reputation to comment) can u give and ip to test and see whats wrong ? and write connecting log

Comment: you can comment on your own stuff, hence you're commenting on your own answer, 

I can't because it's set up on a virtual server that's private to our network and  a connecting log? where would I find the one for the machine?

Comment: set everyone to remote users and see if it works or not